# how to git archive the project directory

Tags: git

my project directory structure is like this:

```
my_project/
    .git/
    a_dir/
    another_file.py
    some_file.py
```

when I run git archive link this:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz -o ../my_project-0.1.0.tar.gz  v0.1.0
```

it archives the contents of my_project, but not the my_project directory. When I untar the archive, by default all of the directories and files are extracted in the current working directory.  I want my archive to expand to a subdirectory called my_project-0.1.0.  Can I do this on the git command line?  Did I set up my repository wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--prefix`. From [the docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html):

> `--prefix=<prefix>/`
>   Prepend `<prefix>/` to each filename in the archive.

Thus you can do:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz --prefix=my_project/ -o ../my_project-0.1.0.tar.gz v0.1.0
```

The trailing `/` is important.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question.

Do the git archive like this:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz --prefix=my_project-0.1.0/ -o ../my_project-0.1.0.tar.gz  v0.1.0
```

Note the trailing / after the prefix.

Comment: It's sort of bad taste, IMO, to answer your own question that is essentially a duplicate of a previous, existing one.